# Value comparison not working properly in some cases Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a comment for my data frame in a new column where if the %stake is greater than 10, the comment should be SOI1&Stake>10. If the %stake is less than 10, the comment should be SOI1&<10, and so on. The code I am trying is as follows.

```
treasury_shares.insert(5, "%Stake",
                           treasury_shares['share_class_level_treasury_shares_as_reported'] / treasury_shares[
                               'issued_shares_as_reported'], True)
    # treasury_shares.insert(6, "SOI priority",soiValues['attribute_value'], True)
    # treasury_shares.loc[:,'%Stake'] *= 100
    # treasury_shares['%Stake'].apply(np.floor)
    treasury_shares['Priority comment']=""

    temp = treasury_shares['%Stake'].astype(float) * 100

    treasury_shares['new_conditional'] = np.where(
        (temp > float(10)) &
        (treasury_shares['SOI priority'].astype('int32') == 1),
        1, 0
    ).astype('int32')

    # Using the mask for your conditionals, where the same column is changed
    treasury_shares['Priority comment'] = np.where(treasury_shares['new_conditional'] == 1,
                                                   'SOI' + (treasury_shares[
                                                       'SOI priority']).astype('string') + '&Stake>10',
                                                   treasury_shares['Priority comment'])

    print(treasury_shares['Priority comment'])
    treasury_shares['%Stake'] = round(treasury_shares['%Stake'] * 100, 0).astype(str) + "%"
    # treasury_shares["%Stake"] = treasury_shares["%Stake"].str.replace(".0", "")
    treasury_shares = treasury_shares.reindex(
        columns=["performance_id", "SOI priority", "total_shares_outstanding_date", "issued_shares_as_reported",
                 "share_class_level_treasury_shares_as_reported",
                 "share_class_level_total_shares_outstanding_as_reported", "%Stake", "Priority comment"])
```

The output I am getting is attached. There we can see for some cases, even if the stake is greater than 10, the comment is not added. In my code, I am adding a new column 'new conditional' and on that basis, I am adding the comment. [image: Output I am getting]

Comment: The code is doing exactly what it should do. You are filling `SOI1&Stake>10` in each row that has `treasury_shares['SOI priority'].astype('int32') == 1` and  `treasury_shares['%Stake'].astype(float) > 10`.

Comment: You are not showing the `SOI Priority` column which might be the cause for the False evaluation

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I wrote the following code.

```
treasury_shares['new_conditional_2'] = np.where(
        (temp > float(10)) &
        (treasury_shares['SOI priority'].astype('int32') == 100),
        1, 0
    ).astype('int32')

    treasury_shares['new_conditional_3'] = np.where(
        (temp < float(10)) &
        (treasury_shares['SOI priority'].astype('int32') == 1),
        1, 0
    ).astype('int32')

    treasury_shares['new_conditional_4'] = np.where(
        (temp < float(10)) &
        (treasury_shares['SOI priority'].astype('int32') == 3),
        1, 0
    ).astype('int32')

    treasury_shares['new_conditional_5'] = np.where(
        (temp < float(10)) &
        (treasury_shares['SOI priority'].astype('int32') == 100),
        1, 0
    ).astype('int32')

    # Using the mask for your conditionals, where the same column is changed
    treasury_shares['Priority comment'] = np.where(treasury_shares['new_conditional'] == 1,
                                                   'SOI' + (treasury_shares[
                                                       'SOI priority']).astype('string') + '&Stake>10%',
                                                   treasury_shares['Priority comment'])

    treasury_shares['Priority comment'] = np.where(treasury_shares['new_conditional_1'] == 1,
                                                   'SOI' + (treasury_shares[
                                                       'SOI priority']).astype('string') + '&Stake>10%',
                                                   treasury_shares['Priority comment'])

    treasury_shares['Priority comment'] = np.where(treasury_shares['new_conditional_2'] == 1,
                                                   'SOI' + (treasury_shares[
                                                       'SOI priority']).astype('string') + '&Stake>10%',
                                                   treasury_shares['Priority comment'])
```